# simulator is not picking up iPhone 5 assets

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I am developing iPhone game using cocos2d 2.0 which does not have support for iPhone 5. now i have updated my settings code and some code in cctexture for picking up the art assets for iPhone 5. i tried to use simulator to debug the exact problem however the simulator is not picking assets for iPhone 5. how should i tackle this problem is there any way other than buying new iPhone 5?

Now i have changed code to identify whether the device is retina display or normal iPhone. It picks correct image now however it is showing only 320X480 part of the 640X960 image. i have attached image to get exact idea [image] the original image looks like [image]

Comment: Please provide more information. What name extension did you put on your iPhone 5 assets?

Comment: i have put  568hHD, however i have changed the suffixes to be check from utils file